# Making a get request from a backend API using axios from vue component

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js

please I am trying to make a get request from an express back end in vuejs. I have the following code in my **BarService.js** file for the get request as below,

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'http://localhost:1230/api/v1/barMan/';

class BarService {
    static getItems() {
        return  async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.get(url);
                const data = res.data;
                resolve(
                    data.map(baritem => ({
                        ...baritem
                    }))
                );
            } catch(err) {
                reject(err);
            }
        };
    }
export default BarService;
```

I also have a **salesEntry.vue** with the following code,

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
    v-for="(baritem, index) in baritems"
    v-bind:key="baritem._id"
    v-bind:index="index" 
    v-bind:item="baritem" 
    >
    <p>{{baritem._id}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BarService from '../BarService';

export default {
  name: 'salesEntry',
  data() {
    return {
      baritems: [],
    }
  },
  async created() {
    try {
      this.baritems = await BarService.getItems();
      console.log(this.baritems);
    } catch(err) {
      this.error = err.message;
    }
  }
</script>
```

I am trying to get the data from the API into the Vue component but its not working. console log gives some function syntax am stack now. Can someone please help me to fix this problem. Thank you all.

Comment: It seems like you are complicating things. Try reading the axios documentation https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Calling `getItems()` returns a function but you aren't calling it. Plus, `async (resolve, reject) ...` won't work, you would need `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... })`. However axios already uses promises; all you need is: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4knhcyds/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing promises and async/await syntax. Just go with one. `axios` returns a promise, so you can just use await to fetch the result and return it.
''axios'' includes

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'http://localhost:1230/api/v1/barMan/';

class BarService {
    static async getItems() {
        const result = await axios.get(url);
        return result.data;
    }
}
export default BarService;
```